# symfony3 & SonataAdmin & Formatter Bundle - Error when using formatter options "target_field" do not exist

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using symfony **3.1.4** and install SonataAdminBundle, SonataFormatterBundle. 
I'm having troubles using the Sonata Formatter Bundle.

1. Install SonataFormatterBundle by this [guide](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html#sonata-admin-integration):
2. I have an Entity: BlogSpost with 3 fields:

> ```
> /**
>  * @var string
>  *
>  * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="blob")
>  */
> private $body;
> /**
>  * @var string
>  *
>  */
> private $rawBody;
> /**
>  * @var string
>  *
>  */
> private $bodyFormatter ;
> ```

3. Here is my formmapper in BlogPostAdmin class

> ```
> class BlogPostAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
> {
>     protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
>     {
>         $formMapper->add('title', 'text')
>             ->add('bodyFormatter', 'sonata_formatter_type', array(
>                 'source_field'         => 'rawBody',
>                 'source_field_options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'span10', 'rows' => 20)),
>                 'format_field'         => 'bodyFormatter',
>                 'target_field'         => 'body',
>                 'event_dispatcher'     => $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getEventDispatcher()
>             ))
>             ->add('draft')
>             ->add('published_time');
>     }
>     // ...
> ```

5. But i receive this error below, when try to create a Post.

> The options "event_dispatcher", "format_field", "source_field", "source_field_options", "target_field" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "horizontal_input_wrapper_class", "horizontal_label_class", "horizontal_label_offset_class", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_render", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "sonata_admin", "sonata_field_description", "sonata_help", "translation_domain", "trim", "validation_groups".
>   500 Internal Server Error - UndefinedOptionsException

**How do I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of compatibility problems with symfony 3.1.4, [option resolver is one of them](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29543399-unfortunately-does-not-work-with-symfony-3-0-1) .
I recommend to try 'formatter-bundle 4.x-dev', where it's fixed among other issues.

Also:

```
    form:
    resources:
        # ...
        - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

is deprecated and

```
    form_themes:    
        - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

should be used instead.